# How to set up the high availability for Azure Data Factory with Azure Integration run-time?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We plan to use the Azure Data factory to handle some of our ETL pipelines. We also planning to use Azure integration runtime since all our data sources and sinks available within the Azure and we don't have any requirements or use cases to use the self-hosted integration runtime.

I found a few resources that discuss how to set up HA/DR for Azure Data factory with self-hosted integration runtime but not for Azure integration runtime. I want to understand or know how to set up HA/DR for Azure data factory with Azure Integration runtime. It would be great if someone helps me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want improve the performance/high availability of Azure integration runtime, you can scale the [Data Integration Unit(DIU)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#data-integration-units) OF Azure integration runtime.

A Data Integration Unit is a measure that represents the power (a combination of CPU, memory, and network resource allocation) of a single unit in Azure Data Factory. Data Integration Unit only applies to Azure integration runtime, but not self-hosted integration runtime.

For more details, you could reference this data Factory document: [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information, it really helps me. Is there any way to auto-scale DIUs?

Comment: @SreeniVasan In usually, default DIUs is enough. As I know, no document and no option provided for us to achieve auto-scale DIUs.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Integration Runtime is **[fully managed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-integration-runtime)**. Hence I do not think there is a need to do anything about it.

[image]

Comment: Many uses hosted integration runtime